# Xampp Syntax Error When Starting Apache line 74

Tags: xampp

I get this error when starting xampp:

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 74 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load modules/mod_access_compat.so into server: The specified
>   module could not be found.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? Please post the httpd.conf file code.

Comment: Yes i have, such as using different port.